# listening to pouchdb changes in particular view returns all documents

Tags: view, replication, synchronization, pouchdb

Trying to retrieve changes in pouchDB for particular view, but still receiving allDocs ... what am I doing wrong? Havent found any tutorials or detailed info how to do this, except pouch API doc (http://pouchdb.com/api.html#changes). I've tested **view** and **filter** options with no luck.

This view is designed and saved as **/notes**

```
function(doc) {
  if (doc.model == 'note') {
    emit(doc._id, doc);
  }
}
```

live changes feed:

```
pouch.changes({ 
  live: true,
  view: '_view/notes'
})
.on('change', function handleUpdate(change) {

  // log changed document
  pouch.get(change.id).then(function(row) {
    console.log(row);
  }

})
```

Maybe the view path is wrong...?
Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

Much more simply, you can do:

```
pouch.changes({ 
  live: true,
  include_docs: true
}).on('change', function (change) {
  if (change.doc && change.doc.model === 'note') {
    console.log(change);
  }
});
```

Trust me; using views in a `changes()` filter is just adding unnecessary complexity and is not going to perform faster. Sorry for not making that clear in the documentation. :)

Comment: Using a view when you want to get the full database content is useless I agree. But what if you want to replicate from a subset of your database. Using a view in allDocs(), changes() and replicate() should be fine, doesn't it ?

Comment: It should work, but TBH I haven't used it much, so I can't guarantee there aren't bugs. And also, you don't get any performance/code complexity benefits from using {view: 'myview'}.

I'll file a bug, though.

Comment: @nlawson There would be some benefits to using `{view: 'myview', filter: '_view'}` if one was using the HTTP adapter, right? (Probably not a common PouchDB use-case, though.) FWIW, @MikulášSychra, I noticed that the `filter: '_view'` option is required if you want to use a view to filter the changes feed, in case you are using the HTTP adapter like me. :-D

Comment: Yes, in the HTTP adapter it avoids sending so much data across the wire. In PouchDB there is zero benefit, because the by-seq store is already indexed for fast changes() lookups. I talk about it a bit [in this video](http://youtu.be/HaGJwV0lwpk?t=7m52s)

Answer (score 0):

BY default changes() will return all the changes from the **beginning** of the database.
So you will receive **ALL** documents change, which is equivalent to a call to allDocs().

To get the changes from a certain point in time, you have to give the option parameter **since**.

From [PouchDB api doc](http://pouchdb.com/api.html):

```
options.since: Start the results from the change immediately after the
given sequence number, you can also pass 'now' if you want only
new changes.
```

You can get a sequence number from a call to **db.info()** or when retrieving a document via **db.get(docId)** with the option **local_seq**.

Comment: If you are doing live changes, you can also do `{since: "now"}` which will simply start listening for changes after the given point in time.